# Поиск на сайте по заданному словосочетанию

Tags: search, php

Подскажите пожалуйста. Есть ли php скрипт либо программа, которые могут пройти по всем страницам сайта (каждую загрузить) и найти на этих страницах заданное словосочетание, показать адреса этих страниц.
Словосочетание не хранится в базе, а подгружается с другого сайта в iframe.

Comment: Гугл с этим справиться легко.

![alt text][1]


[1]: http://cdn-pus-3.pinme.ru/photos/6219bc4ed5aba1ed0f983bf38179e45c_b.jpg

Comment: А еще есть Sphinx http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphinx_(%EF%EE%E8%F1%EA%EE%E2%E0%FF_%F1%E8%F1%F2%E5%EC%E0)